# Set OnScrollListener to AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, scroll

I want first visible position from AutoCompleteTextView List.Is it possible set OnScrollListener to AutoCompleteTextView ? If yes , How can we set it. Is there any way to getting scroll from AutoCompleteTextView ? 
Thanx in Advanced !!!